# Advanced Custom Fields: update_sub_field before saving post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

*Expected behavior:*

When user updates an ACF in the WP dashboard and hits UPDATE, code will check for updated **Status** field and if values have changed, will also modify **Last Updated** field, then save all information.

*Reality:*

The overall content is updated but the **Last Updated** field is not affected by the *update_sub_field* code. However, if I remove the return $post line at the end, the **Last Updated** field is saved, but the overall content reverts back to the original values (not saved).

I need both to be saved! I have a feeling that things are just not happening in the right order and I can accomplish this if I can just figure out the proper filter/action to run, but so far none of these have worked with the below code (have tried different priorities as args, as well):

```
add_action( 'acf/save_post' , 'update_post');
add_action( 'save_post' , 'update_post');
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'update_post');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
function update_post( $post ) {

$projectCount = -1;

if( have_rows('project') ):

    while( have_rows('project') ): the_row();

        $taskCount = -1;
        $projectCount++;

        if( have_rows('project_issue') ):

            while( have_rows('project_issue') ): the_row();

                $taskCount++;

                $oldValue   = get_sub_field('project_current_status');

                $newValue   = $_POST['acf']['field_594afbf65e909'][$projectCount]['field_594afd675e90d'][$taskCount]['field_594c05c666a9f'];

                $date = date('Ymd');

                $updated = ($oldValue !== $newValue) ? 'true' : 'false';

                if ( $updated == 'true' ) { 

                    update_sub_field('project_last_update', $date);

                }

            endwhile;

        endif;

    endwhile;

endif;

return $post;
}
```